# Need To Fetch Mails with SentOn Date

Tags: vba, excel

I've a below code that throwing up error. I need to fetch only mails that received today(current date). Please help to fix this. My other If cases are working fine. Except that Date (SentOn).

My script works like it fetch the email based on the user given time extract the file and created a consolidated sheet. Am trying fetch mail that received on current date.

```
Sub Unzip()
        Dim app As Object
        Dim NS As Object
        Dim InboX As Object
        Dim SubFolder As Object
        Dim MsG As Object
        Dim AtcHmt As Object
        Dim ReceivedHour As Date
        Dim oFrom As Date
        Dim oEnd As Date
        Dim f As Boolean
        '''Variables for unzipping
        Dim FSO As Object
        Dim ShellApp As Object
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
        Dim FileName As Variant
        Dim Ldate As String
        Dim myitem As Object   
        Ldate 
        On Error Resume Next
        Set app = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
        If app Is Nothing Then
            Set app = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
            f = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Set NS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set InboX = NS.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox
        Set SubFolder = InboX.Folders("TEST")
        Set myitem = Outlook.mailitem
        FileNameFolder = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\test\"
        oFrom = CDate(InputBox("Please give Start time" & vbCrLf & _
                                "Example: 9AM", ("Shadowserver report"), "9AM"))
        oEnd = CDate(InputBox("Please give End time" & vbCrLf & _
                                "Example: 6PM", ("Shadowserver report"), "6PM"))

        For Each MsG In SubFolder.Items
        If Ldate = DateValue(myitem.SentOn) Then
            MsG ("Yes")
            ReceivedHour = MsG.ReceivedTime
            If oFrom <= TimeValue(ReceivedHour) And _
                TimeValue(ReceivedHour) <= oEnd Then
                For Each AtcHmt In MsG.Attachments
                    FileName = AtcHmt.FileName
                    If LCase(Right(FileName, 3)) = "zip" Then
                        FileName = FileNameFolder & FileName
                        AtcHmt.SaveAsFile FileName

                        ShellApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere _
                                ShellApp.Namespace(FileName).Items

                        Kill FileName
                        On Error Resume Next
                        FSO.Deletefolder Environ$("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
                    End If
                Next AtcHmt
            End If
        End If
        Next MsG
    End Sub
```

Comment: you can use `Debug.Print DateValue(myitem.SentOn)` to print it into debug window and see if it matches `Debug.Print Ldate`

Comment: Hi peh, again throwing up variable not defined error

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't it be `DateValue(MsG.SentOn)`?

Answer (score 0):

Do nto loop through all items in a folder. Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` along with the restriction on [ReceivedTime] to be in a given range.

Comment: Can you please brief me? am a beginner though.

Comment: My code is checking the received time properly but not the Date. i need to fetch mail by Date also

Comment: "([ReceivedTime] > '6/1/2016 4:00 am') and ([ReceivedTime] < '6/2/2016 4:00 am')"

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is how i driven down to answer

```
Dim Ldate As String

    Ldate = Date

    '''Define the Outlook folder you want to scan
    On Error Resume Next
    Set app = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
    If app Is Nothing Then
        Set app = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
        f = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set NS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set InboX = NS.PickFolder
    'Set SubFolder = InboX.Folders("Shadow Server Reports")
    'Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItems
    '''Define the folder where you want to save attachments
    FileNameFolder = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\test\"

    '''Define the hours in between which you want to apply the extraction
    oFrom = CDate(InputBox("Please give Start time" & vbCrLf & _
                            "Example: 9AM", ("Shadowserver report"), "9AM"))
    oEnd = CDate(InputBox("Please give End time" & vbCrLf & _
                            "Example: 6PM", ("Shadowserver report"), "6PM"))

    For Each MsG In InboX.Items
    If Ldate = DateValue(MsG.SentOn) Then
        ReceivedHour = MsG.ReceivedTime
        If oFrom <= TimeValue(ReceivedHour) And _
            TimeValue(ReceivedHour) <= oEnd Then
            For Each AtcHmt In MsG.Attachments
```